# Using K-Space Filtering to Filter by Speed

Tags: frequency, sound

I want to read waves with an electret consender microphone that are slower than the speed of sound, and I figure it would make those waves easier to identify if I could process out all waves moving around the speed of sound (give or take maybe 20 m/s).

UPDATE: I read that someone did this by "k-space filtering". Is there an easy way to learn how to do this? I'm looking for an acoustic application but most stuff I can find on the internet has to do with MRIs.

Comment: How can your microphone measure speed?

Comment: That's kind of my question. I know in an experiment involving a similar goal the experimenters were able to remove all waves travelling faster than that cutoff, but I'm not sure how. @fibonatic

Comment: I changed my question to make it much clearer, I hope.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on the experimental setup that you want to use?